# How do i uninstall all of the pre-installed games on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 22.04

How can I uninstall all of the pre-installed games in Ubuntu?

I do not use these games and would like to remove them all. I am using a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Does this video answer your question ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bv4a_MAsSo8

Comment: i can't use youtube because of my ISP provider.it doesn't load at all but thanks. that's why i posted the question in stack overflow. but anyways thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To remove all the pre-installed games on ubuntu, run

```
sudo apt purge gnome-games
sudo apt autoremove
```

Or in one line:

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove gnome-games
```

Ok, so a bit of background I was looking at the package page for [ubuntu-desktop](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-desktop) and found nothing about games, and then for the fun of it looked up [gnome-games](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gnome-games) and well I found it. 
The purge command removes all configs and all packages after it. autoremove removes unneeded packages on your system.

Comment: Or in one command: `sudo apt purge gnome-games --autoremove`

Comment: APT accepts a variety of flags to combine effects from subcommands, so `apt autoremove --purge gnome-games` also does the exact same thing.

Comment: @iBug I did not know thx

Answer (score 7):

A distribution comes with a default selection of software. If there is software you want to remove, feel free to remove it.

In "Ubuntu Software", head to the "Installed" tab. This will list all the software that is installed. It is easy to go over the list and remove anything you do not want.

Next time, when you install Ubuntu again, you may prefer to opt for a "Minimum install". Then, only the desktop, a browser and core system utilities (terminal, text editor) are installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that.

1. First of all, you I strongly suggest you install the Synaptic Package Manager with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install synaptic
   ```

   The Synaptic Package Manager will allow you to manage your packages through a GUI. Then, you simply have to locate the packages with the names of the games you want to uninstall in the list, and remove them.

   In the same way, you can uninstall any other piece of software that is included with Ubuntu and you don't need it.
2. If, for some reason, you would rather use the terminal only, you can list all the installed packages with

   ```
    apt list --installed
   ```

   And find the packages you want to uninstall. As the list is usually huge, and the process can get tedious, you can search for a specific package from the list using

   ```
    apt list --installed | grep nameOfPackage
   ```

   The operator "|" allows you to use the output of the first command as the input of the second command. Therefore, first you generate the list of the installed packages, and then you search through this list using the grep tool.

   When you locate the package(s) you want uninstalled, you can simply run

   ```
    sudo apt-get --purge autoremove nameOfPackage
   ```

   This will completely remove the package and its dependencies from your system.
3. You can also use Ubuntu Software, an application provided by Ubuntu in order to install or uninstall software. But keep in mind that there are packages that cannot be found there.

Comment: not a answer is should be a commet

Comment: @Inee a valid answer. One just needs to uninstall the software one does not want installed. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @vanadium A list is explicitly asked for.